# What is the best way to install a WordPress starter theme into a Docker environment?

Tags: docker

I'm recently learning more about starter theme development and would love to get some feedback or tips from any pros here on the forum that have experience in setting up a docker environment for a WordPress starter theme.

To be specific, how do we get an underscores.me theme up and running in Docker?

I'm all ears

Comment: Do you already have WordPress installed in the Docker environment?  If not, see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

Comment: yes I already know how to setup a basic wordpress install with docker.  But how does the process work with installing an underscore.me starter theme?

Comment: I've added an explanation, but I haven't tried this on a Docker environment.  Although I did just follow these steps on another environment.  I'm not sure what would be different on a Docker environment.  Let me know what you run into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to install a theme on WordPress.  There are a couple of options, but for the underscores.me starter theme, the easiest option would be to go to https://underscores.me/ and enter your theme's name and then click the "Generate" button.  Wait a moment, and a zip file should start downloading.

Once you've got the zip file, head over to your WordPress admin and navigate to Appearance -> Themes.  On the themes page, click the "Add New" button and then "Upload Theme" and then follow the prompts to install and activate it.

Have fun!

Comment: You were absolutely correct.  Thanks. I did not know it was as simple as adding my underscore theme from the theme options in WordPress.  With my theme installed, I can now see it added through my Docker Volume location, and begin to modify/brand in detail.  
Many Thanks!

Comment: So happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a more programmatic approach, you could use Composer to require the theme and the Composer Installers package to automatically place that in your themes directory.

This is what I've done with my own local Docker environment. After building and turning on the container, running `composer install` puts the Underscores theme in my themes directory.

See here for more details: 
https://github.com/alexmacarthur/wp-skateboard/blob/starter-theme-underscores/composer.json